# Segmentation fault when instantiating a struct - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, fault

I have a problem trying to load a 3d object from a wavefront file and saving it into a structure that I predefined. I get a segmentation fault error, I`m assuming that I have gone wrong with my pointers somewhere. Here are the sructures:

```
struct vertex
{
    float x,y,z;
};

// the idea is to split each object into groups in order to animate
// them seperately
struct group
{
    float xpos, ypos, zpos;
    float xrot, yrot, zrot;

    int numVertices;
    int numFaces;

    //all verteces
    vertex vertices[MAX_NUM];

    //faces-- a face is made up of one vertex from each of these arrays
    vertex vertexOne[MAX_NUM];
    vertex vertexTwo[MAX_NUM];
    vertex vertexThree[MAX_NUM];
};

struct object
{
    float xpos, ypos, zpos;
    float xrot, yrot, zrot;

    int numGroups;
    group * groups[MAX_NUM];
};
```

This is the function that should load the object:

```
object * loadObject(char * path)
{
object * obj;
obj = new object;

char str[1];
obj->numGroups = 0;
FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");

while(fscanf(file, "%s", str) != EOF)
{
    if(str[0] == 'o')
    {
        obj->numGroups++;
        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1] = new group;

        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numVertices = 0;
        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numFaces = 0;
    }
    else if(str[0] == 'v' && str[1] == ' ')
    {
        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numVertices++;
        sscanf(str, "v %f %f %f",
        &(obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertices[obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numVertices-1].x),
        &(obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertices[obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numVertices-1].y),
        &(obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertices[obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numVertices-1].z));
    }
    else if(str[0] == 'f')
    {
        int one, two, three;
        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numFaces++;
        sscanf(str, "f %i/%*i/%*i %i/%*i/%*i %i/%*i/%*i", &one, &two, &three);

        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertexOne[obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numFaces-1] = obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertices[one-1];
        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertexTwo[obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numFaces-1] = obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertices[two-1];
        obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertexThree[obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->numFaces-1] = obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]->vertices[three-1];
    }
}

fclose(file);
return obj;
}
```

I have tried for quite a while to find the problem but i get no information on the error at all. I know the way I`m assigning the vertices and faces is a bit tedious, any suggesstions for neater code are very welcome. Please tell me if any additional information is needed, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where does the segfault occur? What did you find out while debugging (with a debugger)?

Comment: It's not much C++ code in your example code, only pure C code.

Comment: The fscanf() function when used with %s does non-white space only.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: Yes I was not quite sure about fscanf() the way i used it, Ill go read up on it. Thank you.     All i really need is the first character, how would i scan just that?

Comment: If you want the whole line, so you can do your `sscanf` parsing later, use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`.

Comment: You should check return value of scanf functions, and add debug output after reading something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you do

```
obj->numGroups = 0;
```

Then in some cases you do

```
obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]
```

*without* increasing `obj->numGroups`, meaning you access the array way out of bounds. You also don't check if the array entry been allocated or not.

---

Another problem is that `str` is only one character, and your `fscanf` scans for a string which will put *at least* two character into the string: The actual character you want *and then* the string terminator character. You also access `str[1]` later in the loop, which is out of bounds. All of this is *undefined behaviour* and can lead to crashes.

Comment: It is very possible that the error is due to something like that but i dont quite understand:  "obj->groups[obj->numGroups-1]" is only ever called once i already incremented numGroups, so the -1 should take it back to zero. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: @GermanJohnny Have you tried running it in a debugger? It will help you find _where_ in the code the problem is as well as let you see the callstack, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused it.

Comment: Yes i tried debugging, but it does not actually show me an error. It only complains once i have built and run it saying "segmentation fault" in the running console.

Comment: @GermanJohnny That is a typical sign of an uninitialised variable somewhere. Debuggers normally clears memory, including the stack and areas where global variables are stored.

Comment: The error it throws is : ./geany_run_script.sh: line 5: 4649 Segmentation fault    "./main"          Program exited with code 139

Comment: All the other code did work when I created an object manually(without loading from file) so I am assuming the error is caused by this function. Does the obj pointer need to be global?

Comment: @GermanJohnny  Updated my answer with another probable cause of crashes.

Comment: I added conditions to the if statments making sure that numGroups is geater than zero, still same problem.

Comment: Got rid of str[1] call, still segfault

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would stay away from the various `fscanf()`, `sscanf()`, etc. functions for processing input.  They can be dicey to use.  See this [fscanf man page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) as I think you are assuming a complete string from the fscanf() and you may not be getting it.

The approach I would take would be the following steps: (1) read in a complete string from the file using `fgets()` and (2) use a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) (see also another [article on recursive descent parsing](http://www.cs.engr.uky.edu/~lewis/essays/compilers/rec-des.html)) to parse the string building the object as I go.